# Is unaligned considered to be a "chaos power"?

Tags: alignment, black-crusade

On page 75 of the black crusade core rulebook it states

> **Checking Alignment**
>
> Whenever a Heretic earns 10 Corruption Points (in other
>   words, when they hit the thresholds of 10, 20, 30, and soforth), they check Alignment. This means they compare how
>   many Advancements they have purchased that are affiliated
>   with each Chaos Power. If they have changed Alignment (by
>   having fi ve more advancements dedicated to any one Chaos
>   Power than any other), then they switch their Alignment to
>   the God in question.

Is "unaligned" considered to be a chaos god/power in on itself, and thus requires to have 5 more advances than in any other in order to be unaligned? I've been searching the internet and found couple of forum answers, but I am not sure if they are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Unaligned" means you are not aligned with a particular Chaos god.**

There is a mention about the *Chaos powers* in *Black Crusade - Core Rulebook*, Chapter 1, page 12:

> #### Nurgle
>
> One of the four great Chaos powers is Nurgle.

So there are only four Chaos powers.

There is also a special mention in Chapter 2, page 88:

> #### Keeping A Character Unaligned
>
> Heretics that wish to
> remain unaligned must be careful to balance their selections of Talents. While they may choose any Talents for which they meet the prerequisites, they should avoid over-specialising in any path associated with a specific Ruinous Power. If they choose to accept a disproportionate number of talents or Traits that are tied to a single deity, they instead become associated with that Dark God’s path. As a consequence, they move from being unaligned and become a devotee of that god.

So if you balance your selection, **meaning** you don't have 5 more advancements dedicated to any one Chaos God than any other , you are unaligned.